# Count how many times numbers from a list occur in a list of tupled intervals in Scala

Tags: scala, tuples, accumulator

Say I have a list of tuples:

```
val ranges= List((1,4), (5,8), (9,10))
```

and a list of numbers

```
val nums = List(2,2,3,7,8,9)
```

I want to make a map from tuple in ranges to how many times a given number from nums fall into the interval of that tuple.

Output:

```
Map ((1,4) -> 3, (5,8) -> 2, (9,10) -> 1)
```

What is the best way to go about it in Scala

I have been trying to use for loops and keeping a counter but am falling short.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
val ranges = List((1, 4), (5, 8), (9, 10))
val nums = List(2, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9)

val occurences = ranges.map { case (l, r) => nums.count((l to r) contains _) }
val map = (ranges zip occurences).toMap

println(map) // Map((1,4) -> 3, (5,8) -> 2, (9,10) -> 1)
```

Basically it first calculates the number of occurrences, [3, 2, 1]. From there it's easy to construct a map. And the way it calculates the occurrences is:

- go through the list of ranges
- transform each range into number of occurrences for that range, which is done like this :

  - how many numbers from the list `nums` are contained in that range?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you, it's the good answer and very scala-ish.

Comment: No you didn’t misunderstand it, I believe on a large (l, r) range, contains can be a bottleneck. But I corrected for that myself . This was definitely right

Comment: @Arun Shyam Yes this is inefficient, but I wanted to point you in the direction of thinking about the solution in a different way. BTW if you get a question like this on something like HackerRank, it might even be outside of time constraints and you would in that case be forced to an iterative approach with loops and counters. But whenever I can, I prefer FP solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an efficient single-pass solution:

```
ranges
  .map(r => r -> nums.count(n => n >= r._1 && n <= r._2))
  .toMap
```

This avoids the overhead of creating a list of numbers and then zipping them with the ranges in a separate step.

This is a version that uses more Scala features but is a bit too fancy:

```
(for {
  r <- ranges
  range = r._1 to r._2
} yield r -> nums.count(range.contains)
).toMap
```

This is also less efficient because `contains` has to allow for ranges with a step value and is therefore more complicated.

---

And here is an even more efficient version that avoids any temporary data structures:

```
val result: Map[(Int, Int), Int] =
  ranges.map(r => r -> nums.count(n => n >= r._1 && n <= r._2))(collection.breakOut)
```

See this [explanation of `breakOut`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/breakout.html) if you are not familiar with it. Using `breakOut` means that the `map` call will build the `Map` directly rather than creating a `List` that has to be converted to a `Map` using `toMap`.